# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple when trying to fetch data from the mysql db

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I am getting type error in Flask, saying:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple when trying to fetch data from the mysql db using python

Here is the part of the code

```
if request.form.get('Body') == "SRE1":

   advert = mysql.connection.cursor()
   advert.execute("SELECT message FROM data1 WHERE code='SRE1' ")
    
   myresult = advert.fetchall()
    
   for row in myresult:

       resp.message(row)
       return str(resp)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the problem: Also if in your query you only SELECT one field (`message`) when you iterate through your `myresult` variable, containing all the rows, each row it's considered as an array (obviously an array of **size=1** and with only one element: `message`). 
You can easily solve your problem changing this `resp.message(row)` to this:

```
resp.message(row[0])
```

Comment: Hey thank u it woked i was being troubled with this problem for so long now ..Thank u very much

Comment: the resp.message(row[0]) worked like a charm thank u very much for the help .Thank you much

Comment: Hi Stanley if it helps I'll appreciate if you can upvote the answer and also if you can accept the answer as the solution for your problem for the next users that has your same problem. Thank you!

Comment: For answering your last question I need more information about your code, like what type is 'resp' and where do you want to display them. Also you can try to put the return statement outside the for loop so you don't exit at the first value. Please mark my answer as useful, Thanks!

Comment: Thank you i finally figured it out ..the loop was exiting at the first reply ..as you mentioned there ...Thank you its all working now ..bless you

Comment: Please leave a thumbs up to my answers if it works. Thanks!!